# How to find fields that contains one of array elements?

Tags: python, mongodb

It's easy for find fields that contain an string like this:

```
db.users.findOne({"username" : {$regex : ".*son.*"}});
```

I want to know if there is a way to check all array elements this way?
for example something like this:

```
s = ['one', 'two', 'three']
db.users.findOne({"username" : {$regex : ".*s.*"}});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the native`OR` (`|`) condition of Regex.

Example:

```
s = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
db.users.findOne({"username" : {$regex: ".*(" + '|'.join(s) + ").*"}});
```

Comment: it raise an error: 'list' object has no attribute 'join'

Comment: @ehsanshirzadi sorry, I thought it is in JavaScript (somehow I miss the Python tag). I updated my answer.

Comment: @ehsanshirzadi best answer is this. Your need is just combine all texts you want to find out if username field contains. So take the array and make a big regex string with `or` operator as suggested and give it in `$regex` operator

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one. First you can make `regex` array for s then can use that new array with `$in` operator. like bellow

```
var s = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
s = s.map(function (elm) { return new RegExp(elm, "i"); });
db.users.findOne({username:{$in: s}})
```

Comment: no it's JavaScript code but `map` also in python so you can use `map` in python. @ehsanshirzadi